# Overfull \hbox when using the mdframed package

Tags: warnings, mdframed

**UPDATE: 2011-12-12**

As of 2011-12-12, I can confirm this issue has been resolved on TeXLive-2011.

---

When using the `mdframed` package to generate nice frames for my chemical reactions, I encounter the ever-so-popular warning:

```
Overfull \hbox (20.79999pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--12
```

I'm assuming that it has something to do with the border generated by `mdframed`, but I'm unsure.

My MWE is thus:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[xcolor,linecolor=red]{mdframed}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\section*{Testing the \textsf{mdframed} Package}

\begin{mdframed}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Duis et sem et tortor volutpat placerat id in mauris.
Suspendisse eget tellus sed sem aliquet pellentesque.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

My MWE renders:

[image: MWE for overfull hbox issue with mdframed]

Is there anyway to remedy this warning, or should I simply ignore it?

Comment: I get no warning with that example (after correcting the error about `xcolor`).

Comment: @egreg: What error with `xcolor`?

Comment: @Werner It can be due to the fact that here I have a 2010 TeX Live.

Comment: @egreg: Sure. This warning is produced with `mdframed` [`2011/11/13 v1.0`], regardless of `xcolor`.

Comment: I can confirm that on TeX Live 2011 and mdframed 1.0 the warning is present. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Hm, so it seems as if I've stumbled upon a bug here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of comment I will answer this question.

<sub>This bug was found by Dietrich Grau. At the moment I don't uploaded the new version because I am preparing the dtx-file.</sub>

In Version 1.0 I used a modification of `\makebox` with a calculated `\hsize` for the contents. `\hsize` gets the width of the text without three relevant lengths (`\linewidth`, `\innerleftmargin` and `\innerrightmargin`).

Normally the overfull box is the width of the addition of

```
2linewidth        = .4pt
+innerleftmargin  = 10pt
+innerrightmargin = 10pt
__________________________
overfull box      = 20.8pt
```

In the current development version this bug should be fixed and can be downloaded here: [`mdframed` on github](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed)

Note to compile this version you need the documentclass `ltxmdf` which is available here: [`ltxmdf` on github](https://github.com/marcodaniel/ltxmdf)

If you have any problems with the compilation please contact me.

<sub>PS: I don't know how to create a Makefile for Windows.</sub>

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. (no grammar or orthography `;-)` )